# HTTP Kit WebSocket client

Tags: clojure, websocket, client, http-kit

I'm a bit confused how to create http-kit WebSocket client. On the site there is an example [how to create WebSocket server](http://http-kit.org/server.html#websocket), and creating client is probably trivial but I can't seem to get it right. Any examples out there which are not focused on Javascript clients?

P.S. Some discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446567/clojure-websocket-client-http-kit), but only aleph example, and indication that http-kit now supports WebSocket client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [clj-wamp](http://cljwamp.us/) . The tutorial examples worked out of box for me

```
% git clone https://github.com/cgmartin/clj-wamp-example.git
% cd clj-wamp-example
% lein run
```

[Update] This is mostly server side (although there's a javascript sample client in the tutorial). For client side you may want to check out  [sente](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente) and [chord](https://github.com/jarohen/chord).

Comment: This doesn't seem to address setting up a clojure(script) websocket _client_, but if I'm wrong please correct me and link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: @metasoarous you are about right, i've updated the answer

Comment: FWIW, chord (at the moment) only supports Clojurescript clients (see https://github.com/jarohen/chord/issues/40). Not sure about sente.

Answer (score 7):

There is no Websocket client support yet but there is a feature request to add client support that you could weigh in on: https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/69

Comment: Yeah. That would indeed explain why I couldn't find the correct syntax. :) Thanks.